# Agora Classroom interferes with CSS from website

Tags: nuxt.js, agora.io

I am building a vue2/nuxt which is SPA application but the CSS loaded from the agora script is using generic names which are used in my CSS files as I am using bootstrap.
For example .modal is already declared class but they are trying to redefine it.

How can I make agora.io or my nuxt app act in a way that they won't collide?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as long as I know, agora itself is using bootstrap. Check if the version you are using is the same as agora's.

Comment: @ManiMirjavadi Thanks for the reply, as far as I could debug it they are not using bootstrap, what I made so it doesn't transfer the classes from my SPA app is to force it to open in a new tab `target="_blank"`.